# font_properties error while training tesseract

Tags: tesseract

While training Tesseract, I encountered an error like, `"Failed to load font_properties from font_properties"`. I am running the command -

```
shapeclustering -F font_properties -U unicharset pristina.tr
```

My font_properties file is something `like--> pristina 0 1 0 0 0`.
I am taking help from [this](http://blog.cedric.ws/how-to-train-tesseract-301) blog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to follow Tesseract filename standard for image and box files: `[lang].[fontname].exp[num]`

https://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3